# Can't format RAW Flash Drive

Tags: usb, partitioning, usb-flash-drive, format, raw

I have a 4GB USB Flash Drive which I've accidentally tried to format to FAT (with I think 64k allocation unit, can't remember).
After the format completed, the size of the drive changed to 8mb and it's now RAW.
I've tried recreating the partition with *diskpart* and format, but it says the volume size is too low (same directly through cmd), tried using the EaseUs util as well, nothing.
It won't let me format it to anything else and keeps failing from the start, I can't run HDDGURU's Low Level Format as it says I have under 65k sectors (EaseUs shows 16k).

Is there anything else I could do to recover the drive? I don't care about data, it's empty, I just want it working again.

Here's the outcome of diskpart:

[image: diskpart results]

Here's the HDGURU LLF message:
[image: hdguru results]

Comment: Have you tried to [clean](https://m.windowscentral.com/how-clean-and-format-storage-drive-using-diskpart-windows-10) the drive and repartition it? It might help to provide some screenshots or output of Windows disk management or from the diskpart `list disk` and `list partition` commands.

Comment: Yeah, tried.. modified to attach a screenshot.

Comment: That’s strange. To me it looks like the flash drive has failed.

Comment: Try this [Low Level Format Tool](http://hddguru.com/software/HDD-LLF-Low-Level-Format-Tool/)

Comment: Tried as well, that's the HDGURU tool I've mentioned.. attached a screenshot of that now too.

Comment: Sorry I missed that. I’d have to say the drive has gone bad.